# $L(p,q)$ diffeomorphic to $L(p,q+np)$

Tags: low-dimensional-topology

I'm wanting to show the two lens spaces are diffeomorphic using a Rolfsen twist. I know under this Kirby move, the resulting framing co-efficient of $\frac{p}{q}$ surgery is $\frac{p}{q+np}$, so I feel like there is some good relation here. Any help would be great.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.